# SurveyMonkey PHP Issue

Tags: php, api, survey

Background:
I want to conduct a survey with surveymonkey. I have a panel/sample which is provided by an external company. The survey is ready for use.

Problem:
The panel providing company wants me to use their "participationID" with a PHP-link, which is automatically linked with each participant.

Steps:

1. The company wants to forward individual participants to a surveylink such as [this](http://www.someexamplesurveyprovider.com/survey/start.php?participation_id=123456780670d68949a0d).
2. After the survey, the company wants to get a redirect link with information such as "completed" or "screenout".

Has someone an idea regarding this issue?
I tried the documentation of the surveymonkey API, but I find a bunge of information how to get data from surveymonkey *after* collecting all data.